# Database delete query

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

i am designing a student management system with php and mysql 
where there is organisation having student and teacher 
example 
there is organisation=stackoverflow.com it has two types of user employee and client 
all the details of organisations connected to us are stored in table X 
and there employee detail in table Y 
and there client detail in table Z
there are many different organisation and they all have different client and employee 
**Now if i delete a org from table x i want its all detail to get deleted from database(including its all employee and client from table y and z respectively )**
is there any way to this only with database(mysql) or i have to write a app program to do it

Comment: You can do it in newer versions of MySQL using [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html).

Comment: Jay blanchard  can you tell me more about it i dont know much about mysql db

Comment: You need to read about this, there is too much to tell in a comment or two and the question is far too broad for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this easily by declaring `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE organizations (
    org_id PRIMARY KEY;
    name
);

CREATE TABLE clients (
    id PRIMARY KEY;
    FOREIGN KEY (org_id) 
    REFERENCES organizations (org_id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE employees (
    employee_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (org_id) 
    REFERENCES organizations (org_id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

More info:
[Tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/)
[MySQL Reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)